# Files not readable on Windows

Tags: 12.04, windows, video, filesystem, vlc

I have a video server running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, which works fine for what I need it to do.

Although, as it is a video server from which I stream movies to my Windows machine, that's what I expect it to do.

The last time I watched a movie using this method, was yesterday, when I could watch the movie without any issues whatsoever.

Although now, I tried opening a .mp4 video file and a .VOB file, having tried both in VLC and in Windows Media Player. Neither worked, VLC gave me the error "Bad File Descriptor" and WMP simply stated that the file could not be opened.

I tried opening the .mp4 file which I viewed yesterday, which didn't work anymore either.

Is there anyone who knows what may be causing this issue and/or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try using a different port and/or path?

Comment: I've tried everything, including going to the actual media center & playing the files directly from the hard drive, which didn't work.

It's fixed now though, it ended up being a faulty hard drive which my dad hooked up to the machine & it was causing problems for some reason.